# Vaadin layout break line without panel

Tags: layout, label, line, vaadin, break

I know it is possible for labels to automatically break lines when in a panel. 
Is there a way to have labels break lines when the text would be over a layouts width?

**UPDATE**
OK i tried it with "800px" width now instead of "100%" and now the labels are having line breaks. Whats the reason for this behaviour? And how can I workaround this then for a percentual sizing of layouts as this is important for my page?

It  currently looks like in the image below, the text is just cut off.

[image: It currently looks like this]

Extracted Code showing the setup:

```
    VerticalLayout labelLayout= new VerticalLayout();
    labelLayout.setWidth("100%");
    labelLayout.addComponent(usernameLabel);
    labelLayout.addComponent(postLabel);
    labelLayout.addComponent(ratioLabel);
    labelLayout.addComponent(lowestRatedPost);
    labelLayout.addComponent(highestRatedPost);

    detailsLayer.addComponent(labelLayout);
    wrappercontent.addComponent(detailsLayer);
    wrapper.addComponent(wrappercontent);
```

Comment: what are the surrounding containers? it would greatly help to have the code for the minimal failing case.

Comment: Thanks. I updated th epost, is it more understandable now?

Comment: Have you read this https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.label.html#components.label.wrap ?

Comment: Yes, and I saw the panel example (it works perfectly with panels) + "such as HorizontalLayout, so you need to pay special care with them." 
I just saw I removed too much in my code extract I put above - I set the width with 
labelLayout.setWidth("100%");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly this problem, and managed to solve it using this CSS. Vaadin Labels have the CSS attribure *white-space: nowrap* which is what is stoping your text wrapping as you expect it to.

```
.v-label
{
   white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: That was it! Many thanks Chris, simple and great help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure there is a good reason that Vaadin chose for labels not to wrap, but I don't know what it is.